# How do you delete all lines that contain double quotes in sh?

Tags: macos, sed, terminal, sh

I tried 
`sed -ne '/\"/!p' theinput > theproduct`
but that got me nowhere. It didn't do anything. What can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape quote. Write:

`sed '/"/d' theinput > theproduct`

or

`sed -i '/"/d' theinput`

to alter the file directly.

In case you have other quotes as @Jonathan Leffler suggests, you have to find out which ones. Then, using \x you can achieve what you want. \x is used to specify hexadecimal values.

`sed -i '/\x22/d' theinput`

The line above would delete all rows in theinput containing the ordinary (ASCII 34) quote. You'll have to try the code points Jonathan suggested.

Comment: In what way did it not work?  On my MacOS X terminal using `/bin/sh` as the current shell, it worked fine.  Is there any chance you're dealing with UTF-8 data and magic double quotes (not ASCII 34, or Unicode U+0022, but something else)?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
grep -v '"' theinput > theproduct
```

Comment: maybe if you were to post a sample of your input we could help you better.

Comment: Show us the output too, if any.

Comment: @t3hcakeman: It does what you asked about. Perhaps your input isn't what you think it is, or perhaps you did not inspect the output file `theproduct` properly?

Answer (score 1):

The command you showed us should have worked.

```
$ cat theinput 
foo"bar
foo.bar
$ sed -ne '/\"/!p' theinput > theproduct
$ cat theproduct 
foo.bar
$
```

unless you're using csh or tcsh as your interactive shell.  In that case, you'd need to escape the `!` character, even within quotation marks:

```
% cat theinput 
foo"bar
foo.bar
% sed -ne '/\"/!p' theinput > theproduct
sed -ne '/"/pwd' theinput > theproduct
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command
% rm theproduct 
% sed -ne '/\"/\!p' theinput > theproduct
% cat theproduct 
foo.bar
%
```

But that's inconsistent with your statement that "It didn't do anything", so it's not clear what's really going on (and the question is tagged [bourne-shell](/questions/tagged/bourne-shell) anyway).

But there are much simpler ways to accomplish the same task, particularly the `grep` command suggested by @Mike Sokolov.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have 'ASCII' input?  Could you have Unicode (UTF-8) with characters that are not not ASCII 34, or Unicode U+0022, but something else?

Alternative Unicode 'double quotes' could be:

- U+2033 DOUBLE PRIME; U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK;
- U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK;
- U+201F DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK;
- U+02DD DOUBLE ACUTE ACCENT;
- (and there could easily be others I've left out).

You can look to debug this with the `od` command:

```
$ cat theinput
No double quote here
Double quote " here
Unicode pseudo-double-quotes include “”‟″˝.
$ od -c theinput
0000000    N   o       d   o   u   b   l   e       q   u   o   t   e    
0000020    h   e   r   e  \n   D   o   u   b   l   e       q   u   o   t
0000040    e       "       h   e   r   e  \n   U   n   i   c   o   d   e
0000060        p   s   e   u   d   o   -   d   o   u   b   l   e   -   q
0000100    u   o   t   e   s       i   n   c   l   u   d   e       “  **
0000120   **   ”  **  **   ‟  **  **   ″  **  **   ˝  **   .  \n        
0000136
$ od -x theinput
0000000      6f4e    6420    756f    6c62    2065    7571    746f    2065
0000020      6568    6572    440a    756f    6c62    2065    7571    746f
0000040      2065    2022    6568    6572    550a    696e    6f63    6564
0000060      7020    6573    6475    2d6f    6f64    6275    656c    712d
0000100      6f75    6574    2073    6e69    6c63    6475    2065    80e2
0000120      e29c    9d80    80e2    e29f    b380    9dcb    0a2e        
0000136
$ odx theinput
0x0000: 4E 6F 20 64 6F 75 62 6C 65 20 71 75 6F 74 65 20   No double quote 
0x0010: 68 65 72 65 0A 44 6F 75 62 6C 65 20 71 75 6F 74   here.Double quot
0x0020: 65 20 22 20 68 65 72 65 0A 55 6E 69 63 6F 64 65   e " here.Unicode
0x0030: 20 70 73 65 75 64 6F 2D 64 6F 75 62 6C 65 2D 71    pseudo-double-q
0x0040: 75 6F 74 65 73 20 69 6E 63 6C 75 64 65 20 E2 80   uotes include ..
0x0050: 9C E2 80 9D E2 80 9F E2 80 B3 CB 9D 2E 0A         ..............
0x005E:
$ sed '/"/d' theinput > theproduct
$ cat theproduct
No double quote here
Unicode pseudo-double-quotes include “”‟″˝.
$
```

(`odx` is my own command for dumping data in hex.)